# Is there a way to find why cabal installed a certain package?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-install, ghc-pkg

When installing a package with cabal-install, it will also indirectly install all the dependencies. Given a certain package in my `.cabal/packages` folder that I didn't directly install, is there a way to find what other package(s) it was a dependency of?

Comment: You might also like [this reverse dependencies tool](http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse), though it won't be specific to your installed packages.

Comment: btw, the latest `cabal-install` [gained the ability to print depedency information](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/2569)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found this command somewhere (can't remember where now) and use it regularly to produce a dependency graph of my installed packages:

```
ghc-pkg dot | tred | dot -Tpng > pkgs.png
```

Note that it's actually `~/.ghc` which contains the installed package information, rather than `~/.cabal`.

You can also use:

```
ghc-pkg unregister <pkgname>
```

which will print a list of packages which would break if you uninstalled this package, which is effectively what you are looking for:

```
$ ghc-pkg unregister aeson
ghc-pkg: unregistering aeson would break the following packages: criterion-0.8.0.0 yesod-1.2.4 .... (use --force to override)
```

#### Update

Using `dot -Tsvg > pkgs.svg` in the above command also allows you to use text searches (if you open the file in a browser, for example).

Also, the [cab](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cab) utility is very useful for showing dependencies and reverse dependencies, amongst other things.

For stack users `stack dot --external` can be used from your project directory in place of the above `ghc-pkg dot`.

Comment: The resulting graph was a bit messy but `ghc-pkg dot | grep my-package` helped me find what I was looking for.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. For the benefit of others, I found that if you're doing this in the context of a cabal sandbox, you can use ```cabal sandbox hc-pkg dot``` instead of ```ghc-pkg dot```

Answer (score 3):

I found [cabal-db](https://github.com/vincenthz/cabal-db) to be helpful. For example, you can run

```
cabal-db revdeps semigroupoids
```

and it will tell you

```
zippers: semigroupoids (>=4 && <5)
wl-pprint-extras: semigroupoids (>=3 && <5)
vector-instances: semigroupoids (>=3)
validation: semigroupoids (>=4.0)
transformers-abort: semigroupoids (>=1.2)
these: semigroupoids (>=1.0 && <4.1)
```

etc...